# php simpleXML addChild containing existing text node

Tags: php, simplexml

I want to take an existing element and put a child inside of it. But I want the content of the  pre-existing element to go inside the new element as well.

So I have `<span class="folnum">Content</span>` and I want to end up with `<span class="folnum"><a href="link">content</a></span>` and I was hoping I could do this with php's simpleXML parser.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$folnum = $xmldoc->xpath("//span[@class='folnum']");
foreach ($folnum as $indivfolnum)
{
    $child = $indivfolnum->addChild("a", "wholemsImage");
    $child->addAttribute("href", (string) $indivfolnum);
}
```

What I get from this is `<span class="folnum">Content<a href="link">wholemsImage</a></span>`.

Obviously the `addChild()` method is adding new content as well, which is not really what I want. I want it to replace the text-content.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

1. Save the `Content` to new variable: `$link = (string) $indivfolnum;`
2. Clear the `<span>` element: `$indivfolnum[0] = "";`
3. Then append new child.

Code example:

```
$folnum = $xmldoc->xpath("//span[@class='folnum']");
foreach ($folnum as $indivfolnum)
{
    $link = (string) $indivfolnum;
    $indivfolnum[0] = "";
    $child = $indivfolnum->addChild("a", "wholemsImage");
    $child->addAttribute("href", $link);
}
```

It creates the output as you want it:

`<span class="folnum"><a href="Content">wholemsImage</a></span>`

Comment: That's a clever idea. But it looks to me like it doesn't work. I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in /home/jeffr306/public_html/plaoul/text/textdisplay.php on line 145

Comment: I think the problem that the addChild method only works on an "simpleXML" object. But when we declare `$indivfolnum` as empty we are declaring at it as absolutely null, not as an empty "simpleXML" object.

Comment: @Jeff: [here's](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=235456.0) a different approach: start one lvl higher (not from `<span>` element), check `if ($body['span'] = 'content') $body['span'] = '<a href="link">content</a>'`

Comment: @Jeff: check [Updating a node value with PHP's simpleXML and xpath not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383133/updating-a-node-value-with-phps-simplexml-and-xpath-not-working) and [php and simpleXml - how to change node contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420499/php-and-simplexml-how-to-change-node-contents)

Comment: [`SimpleXMLElement::addChild()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) requires at least PHP 5.1.3. You did get the fatal error because your PHP version was too low.

Comment: @Jeff: It would be cool if you could mark this as the answer, it's correct, I've just reviewed this question.